# Why does Python's reduce raise a TypeError when used to sum a list of lists?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I was under the impression that I would get the sum of elements in lists of a list if I used `reduce` as follows:

```
reduce(lambda x, y: x[0]+y[0], [[1],[2],[3],[4],[5]])
```

However I get the error saying:

```
TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

What is reduce doing in this case? And if I do want to sum, what is the best way that avoids a `for` loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use reduce like that, you'll have to provide the initial value:

```
>>> list_of_lists = [[1],[2],[3],[4],[5]]
>>> reduce(lambda x, y: x+y[0], list_of_lists, 0)
15
```

But don't use `reduce` for this.  Just use [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sum) built-in:

```
>>> sum(n for sublist in list_of_lists for n in sublist)
15
>>> sum(n for [n] in list_of_lists)  # enforcing 1-element sublists
15
```

Answer (score 0):

There's not really much reason to throw everything in a sublist. This is really what you're going for.

```
reduce(lambda x, y: x+y, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
```

If all you're doing is summing elements of a list, Python has a built-in for that.

```
sum([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
```

If you really have some reason to need lists of lists, then you need the accumulated value to be a list as well. Think of it this way: the function you pass to `reduce` should usually return a value of the same "type" (using the word "type" very loosely here) as the first argument, as it will be later passed in as the first argument to another call.

```
reduce(lambda x, y: [x[0]+y[0]], [[1], [2], [3], [4], [5]])
```

Comment: I simplified my problem into a list of list of numbers, but yeah I had to work with that format. It makes sense that one would save the reduction as a list...